# How to publish live video in facebook iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Recording video through rear camera and facebook live button which will ask permission to login after successful login. It will allow user to share live video in facebook.

Right now i can able login facebook but it does not allow to publish live stream in facebook. It show error in iPad like this:

Invalid Scopes: public_actions. This message is only shown to developers. User of your app will ignore these permission if present. Please read the documentation for valid permission at: https://developers.facebook/docs/facebook-login/permissions

Also here is the screenshot of publish live stream video error [image]

Comment: You need to ask and get permission for `publish_actions` which will allowed use to post on Facebook.

Comment: How to ask permission publish_actions @PaulMarshal

Comment: You should check here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/permissions, under ***"Check for Permissions"***, Just updated link, please check again

Comment: @PaulMarshal i have given 
func start() {
        guard FBSDKAccessToken.current().hasGranted("publish_actions") else {
            return self.delegate.liveVideo(self, didErrorWith: FBSDKLiveVideo.errorFromDescription(description: "The \"publish_actions\" permission has not been granted"))
        }

Comment: I didn't getting you.

Comment: @PaulMarshal i tried by giving guard FBSDKAccessToken.current().hasGranted("publish_actions")

Comment: You need to ask for `"publish_actions"` permission due to permission not granted.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#live-api-4-24